# how to do two tasks in on pipeline ETL - DataFrame -DataFlow - BigQuery

Tags: dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataflow

This is my code written in BigQuery in Google Cloud:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio import GcsIO
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem import GCSFileSystem
import argparse
import logging
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json
from google.cloud import storage
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
from apache_beam import pvalue

# Load configuration from a JSON file
with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

credintial = config['project']
project_name = credintial['project_name']
dataset_name = credintial['dataset_name']
table_name_source = credintial['table_name_source']
table_name_target = credintial['table_name_target']
department = credintial['department']
file_name = credintial['file_name']
bucket = credintial['bucket']
table_schema = credintial['table_schema']
output_table_name = "{}.{}".format(dataset_name, table_name_source)

today = datetime.date.today()
today = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")

class ReadExcel(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, file_path):
       with GcsIO().open(file_path, "rb") as file:
            excel_df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    return [row.fillna('').to_dict() for _, row in excel_df.iterrows()]

class MergeTables(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, project_name):
        self.project_name = project_name
        
def process(self, element):
    sql = f"""
        MERGE `{project_name}.{dataset_name}.{table_name_target}` t
        USING `{project_name}.{dataset_name}.{table_name_source}` s
        ON t.purchase_requisition = s.purchase_requisition AND t.pr_item = s.pr_item
        WHEN MATCHED AND t.hashed_row != s.hashed_row THEN
        UPDATE SET
            all other columns...
            t.hashed_row = s.hashed_row
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (all other columns..., hashed_row)
        VALUES (all other columns..., s.hashed_row)
    """
    client = bigquery.Client(project=self.project_name)
    query_job = client.query(sql)
    query_job.result()  # Wait for the query to complete
```

these are my 2 classes, The first one is to Read my data from Excel that is saved in cloud storage and then I will write this data in BigQuery,
the second class is about Merge between 2 tables, Source and Target Table.

so my goal is to Read and write data into BigQuery in the Source Table after it is finished I want to check target table has the same data in the source (the new record) or not if there is a change in the hash value then do an update if not insert it if new record.

I want to do the first task (Read and Write) and then do the second task (MergeTable)
how can I define this in the pipeline, because it give errors and not work:

```
def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        required=False,
                        help='Output BQ table to write results to.',
                        default=output_table_name)
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        gcs = GCSFileSystem(PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))

        # Match the files in GCS
        match = gcs.match([f'gs://{bucket}/smb-data/{today}/{department}/{file_name}.xlsx'])
        
        if match:
            file_metadata = match[0]

            excel_data = (
                p | 'Read and Write file' >> beam.Create([file_metadata.path])
                  | 'Read Excel' >> beam.ParDo(ReadExcel())
            )

            # Write the combined Excel data to BigQuery
            _ = (
                excel_data
                | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    known_args.output,
                    schema=table_schema,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
                )
            )

            # Merge the tables
            _ = (
                p | 'Dummy' >> beam.Create([None])
                | 'Merge Tables' >> beam.ParDo(MergeTables(project_name))
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? I see the first code classes/functions never gets called & how does the second one relate to first? Do share the errors too..

Comment: As you can see in the second part I call the first class: 'Read Excel' >> beam.ParDo(ReadExcel())
also, I call the 2nd class: 'Merge Tables' >> beam.ParDo(MergeTables(project_name))

Comment: The 2 classes are not related to each other but they depend on each other, I can't run 2nd class before making sure the first one is done.

Comment: My problem is when you want to write to big query you can't run other tasks after it, I fixed this problem but with 2 pipelines, I don't want that, I want the same pipeline to run 2 tasks related to each other.

Comment: Could you share the error message you are facing? By providing this information, community members can learn more about the issue and help you find a solution.